# Block expands more than the height of content when using collapsiblock module?

Tags: 7, blocks

I have applied the collapsible property to one of the block using [Collapsiblock](https://www.drupal.org/project/collapsiblock) in Drupal 7. everything working fine, but the issue is that, after clicking for slide, it slides more than the content height and then after again in back slides and then fits to the content. I want that it just slide till its content and stops on first instance. Please see attached Image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a wild guess (no time to test this) but you could try some of the following and see if this will make a difference:

1. Try using a different version of jQuery (download and install [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) and then go to Configuration>Development>jQuery update and test different versions. Don't forget to clear the cache every time before the test).
2. Try tinkering with your CSS classes for the block and its contents to include a max-height: 100% property. For example, try this for the ID of the block (e.g. #block-block-2) and/or for the .content class inside that block (#block-block-2 .content)

Comment: It's Perfect. First option worked perfectly, just installed module and cleared the cache and done. Very Thanks...